# BindException Address Already in Use

Tags: android, sockets

I'm having issues with my serverThreadProc() method. It throws a BindException whenever I run it. Thinking there might be an issue in the first two lines of the try block. Not sure what I'm doing wrong though.

```
private void serverThreadProc() {
    while (!this.stopRequested) {
        Socket sessionSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
            sessionSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
            InetAddress sourceAddress = sessionSocket.getInetAddress();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Accepted new incoming connection ... "
                    + sourceAddress.toString());
            if (clientMap.containsKey(sourceAddress)) {
                ClientProcessor legacyProcessor = clientMap
                        .get(sourceAddress);
                legacyProcessor.shutdown();
            }
            ClientProcessor processor = new ClientProcessor(sessionSocket);
            processor.start();
            clientMap.put(sourceAddress, processor);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public int start() {
    try {
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
        this.serverPort = this.serverSocket.getLocalPort();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Server " + serverName + " started at "
                + this.serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
    }

    this.serverThread.start();
    return this.serverPort;
}

public void stop() {
    try {
        stopRequested = true;
        if (this.serverSocket) {
            this.serverSocket.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
    }

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "The server " + this.serverName + " has been stopped.");
}
```

Here is the stack trace produced by the code:

```
01-11 05:51:53.472: I/ConnectActivity(2151): IP Address:0
01-11 05:51:53.492: I/ServiceServer(2151): Server Whooznear started at /0.0.0.0:35434
01-11 05:51:53.522: I/ConnectActivity(2151): Started at 35434
01-11 05:51:53.542: W/System.err(2151): java.net.BindException: Address already in use
01-11 05:51:53.542: W/System.err(2151):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.bind(Native Method)
01-11 05:51:53.542: W/System.err(2151):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.bind(BlockGuard.java:275)
01-11 05:51:53.571: W/System.err(2151):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:165)
01-11 05:51:53.571: W/System.err(2151):     at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:123)
01-11 05:51:53.592: W/System.err(2151):     at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:74)
01-11 05:51:53.592: W/System.err(2151):     at com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer.serverThreadProc(ServiceServer.java:63)
01-11 05:51:53.592: W/System.err(2151):     at com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer.access$0(ServiceServer.java:58)
01-11 05:51:53.611: W/System.err(2151):     at com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer$1.run(ServiceServer.java:53)
```

Comment: Address alreay in use means that some other application is already using that port number. Close that application before running your application, or just change your port number. POssibility is that your own application might be running in background and you didnt notice it.

Comment: I know nothing about Andoid, but normall you need a `listen` before an `accept`.

Answer (score 1):

You create `ServerSocket` in the procedure `start()`, then you create new `ServerSocket` on the same port in the procedure `serverThreadProc()`. You have to close old one before you create new server socket. Or use another port.

Answer (score 0):

Why are u using `while` in the method `serverThreadProc()`

Make the program simple.I think your code is a bit messy.

You may refer to basic socket examples

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html

This may help you to simplify ur code for the task